# What are the requirements for Oculus Direct-to-rift mode?

Tags: windows, opengl, oculus

I am having issues making my Oculus application to render in the HMD (using direct-to-rift mode)
I am mostly taking code from the TinyWorld OpenGL demo, and while it does everything right in the monitor, it just wont turn the Oculus on and show my output there. I am not sure why, and I don't know how to diagnose it.
My calls to ovrHmd_EndFrame appear to be successful but unlike in TinyWorld they don't make my monitor flicker briefly and turn on the HMD (like TinyWorld does)

What are the requirements for an application to reach Direct-to-Rift mode? Maybe I am missing something.

- Is it the Pixel format?
- Resolution?
- Could it hurt that I am also using DirectX and communicating with it through the Nvidia DirectX OpenGL
  interop?
- How can I diagnose it?

I am on SDK 0.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FWIW I wasn't able to get direct mode to work with OpenGL until the 0.5.0.1 SDK and even then it only worked with the latest NVIDIA drivers at the time. Although the Oculus example worked in direct mode with GL there are lots of developers who had problems with it. People were trying every initialization order under the sun (including the one from the example) but nobody could get it to work. I'd suggest moving up to 0.7.0.0 & NVIDIA 355.84.

Comment: Yeah. Windows 10 is going to force me to do that. I probably should take the hit now of porting forward.